# Jenkins CI not available in Gitlab Integrations

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Im working in GitLab and Jenkins Integrations. Its working fine in scheduling process.
I'm trying CI from GitLab with Jenkins. All the blogs and tutorials explained with JenkinsCI But that option is not available  in GitLab->Integrations. [GitLab-Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYzsp.png) please refer the image.

I have tried without Jenkins CI using webhook getting the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd1sC.png)

Error: Webhook executed successfully But returning Http 500
I have tried my personal account in that I can see the jenkins under Integration able to add setting then moved to Active Integration

Comment: should this maybe be a tech support question to Gitlab? It doesn't seem to be a community question.

Comment: @AdamSmith thanks for the comment. any process to raise a question to gitlab tech support.